# clear cookies and redirect in WebView from Java code

Tags: android

Building an web app application using WebView which has "login page" and a "content(uses javascript) page". The login session is managed using cookie. To keep the app simple i dont want to add the logout option on the web page.

The desired behavior is to add the "log out" item to the "action overflow" which will be outside the WebView and on activating the "log out" item, the cookies must be cleared and the "login page" should be requested by the WebView. How to achieve this from java code.

The WebView code looks like below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v("MYAPP", "IN MainActivity before");
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/loginpage");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog article on the Android Developers blog that gives you an example of communicating between native app code and javascript in a web view >

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/using-webviews.html

You can run javascipt functions in the Webview with something like this;

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:logout()");
```

Also check out [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) for communicating from the webview back to the native app (and its limitations), which is all in the blog article.

Hope this helps.